# Exploded list of integers still has object datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written a code which finds whether any columns in my table is a list, if it is a list it should check whether the list contains integers and if so it should convert the datatype from an `object` to `int`.

I have managed to convert the values to `int` but when I check the data types for the columns it still shows the column as `object`.

Why is that? Is it because the column itself needs to be changed to an `int` not just the values?

Dataframe:
[image]

Current Code:

```
x = (docs.applymap(type) == list).all()
y = x.index[x].tolist()
for i in y:
    docs = docs.explode(i)
    if (docs[i].str.isdigit().all()) == True:
        docs[i].apply(lambda x: int(x)) 

print(docs.dtypes) #shows that the column is still an `object`
```

[image]

[image]

DataIds should be converted to an `int` because it has been exploded and is just integers now but the column still shows it as having an `object` datatype.

Comment: Please share  a sample of dataframe with expected output for better clarity.

Comment: you cant change the type of the column with the lists. If it contains lists it's an object.

Comment: If you want to check if it contains 1 integer, then it can be

Comment: i've updated my code, basically i'm performing an explode on the column which contains a list, but when it has been exploded it still shows the integers as an `object` datatype, so I need to change the datatype of the exploded list to integers if that's possible

Comment: There's a big difference between a column containing list of ints (which probably needs the Object type) and the column containing a one and only one int (which could take the int type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue with the `explode()` function is that because a list has a datatype of `object` even when it has been exploded, whether or not it was a list of integers, it will still carry the `object` datatype.

So if you have a list of integers and you want to explode that list then convert that column to `int`, use the following code:

```
docs = docs.explode(i)
if (docs[i].str.isnumeric().all()) == True:
      x = (docs[i].to_frame().columns)
      docs[x] = docs[x].astype(int)
```